# Can't obtain UberPool in Sydney

Tags: uber-api

I'm testing uberpool in Sydney but uber API does not return any 'pool' products. The same query through uber app got 'pool' results.
It's important to mention that I can get pool results in other cities like San Francisco.

Is this behavior expected in Sydney or am I missing something?

Comment: If the pool product requires walking somewhere, it wouldn't return via API (since there is no way to give walking instructions in the API currently). So it is returned in SF because you don't have to walk somewhere...your pickup address is specified. I would guess in Sydney that pool product requires walking. 

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/uber-developers/pool|sort:date/uber-developers/s0zfV3WtQUg/jcTFa7jXAgAJ

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/uber-developers/pool%7Csort:date/uber-developers/BVyLiLBnp2o/oNliRSD_AgAJ